# Character moves in unity after some time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, character

I have 2 characters and one car. I want to do when the car reache a certain z position like -0.02 or 0.02. the characters need to start walking. Before that character will be stopped at that place.

Does anyone have an idea how can I approach this idea in unity?

"All characters are made in Fuse and mixamo software".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way would be detecting the position in the update, then in Cinemachine you can animate the camera getting close to the car while it stops, then in Timeline you open the car door and animate the character making it leave the car and stand, take a short pause, then start the walk animation in Timeline, while moving to a different camera in Cinemachine.

Comment: I can do that but the character is different and character needs to come in front of the car. So, the car will hit that person.

Comment: The same principle applies. If this is an animation you can drive all of it via Timeline and Cinemachine.

Answer (score 0):

The character starts with an initial velocity of 0

```
private Transform car;

private void Update()
{
    if(car.transform.position.z > - 0.02 || car.transform.position.z < 0.02)
    {
        StartMovingCharacter();
    }
}

private void StartMovingCharacter()
{
    // Changes the velocity of the Character which would make the Character move
}
```

Something like this will do it.

Comment: In character moving, I don't have a script to move the character. but actually, this is a good script but what should I write in StartMovingCharater() function? In moving character I animation everything.

Comment: The animation starts in the StartMovingCharater() function, which would start to move the character.

Comment: I used this "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXCZ-n5VyJc&ab_channel=GameDevGuide" type of waypoint to walk in character.

Comment: I try this code if (car.transform.position.z >= 0.34936 || car.transform.position.z <= 0.4864168)
  {
   animator.SetBool("IsWalking", true);} else
        {
   animator.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
        }

Comment: but it's not working. if car is not that position character is still walking.